# AngularJs mysteries

Tags: angularjs

I really thought I'm getting the hang of AngularJs slowly - but seems I'm still totally green.....

I tried to put together a tiny demo to show the `ng-repeat` directive, and now *nothing* works - I'm just getting a blank screen, and I have *no clue* as to why....

Can anyone enlighten me??

This is my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <!-- include link to Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- include app.js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller as vm">
        <label>My company:</label>
        <hr>
        <div id="divTeam" ng-repeat="m in vm.team">
            <p>
                {{m.firstname}} {{m.name}} ({{m.tag}})
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my `app.js` file (same directory):

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {
            $scope.team = [
                { name: "Brown", firstname: "Leo", tag: "lebr" },
                { name: "Smith", firstname: "Adrian", tag: "adsm" },
                { name: "Loflin", firstname: "Wes", tag: "welo" },
                { name: "Hackett", firstname: "John", tag: "joha" }
            ]
        }
    );
```

I don't get it....

- I'm creating the Angular module called `myapp`
- I reference that module in the `<body ng-app="myapp">` tag
- I'm creating an Angular controller called `mycontroller`
- I reference that in the `<div ng-controller="mycontroller as vm">` tag
- I'm creating an array of objects on the `$scope`
- I was expecting to be able to iterate over this array of objects using the `ng-repeat="m in vm.team"` directive

but all I get right now is an empty screen with just the title "My company:" - and nothing else.....

- I checked the URL to the Angular JS file - it's correct as far as I can tell.
- I checked the Javascript console in IE or Chrome - no errors or info messages to be seen anywhere.....
- If I add just a plain little expression like `{{1+2}}` to my HTML, it does get evaluted to "3", so I'm pretty sure Angular is up and running....

So what am I missing? (I'm a long-time .NET developer, always struggling with all things Javascript.....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use controllerAs syntax, when writing `ng-controller="mycontroller as vm"`, you have to bind your data to `this` instead of `$scope`

```
   app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {
        this.team = [
            { name: "Brown", firstname: "Leo", tag: "lebr" },
            { name: "Smith", firstname: "Adrian", tag: "adsm" },
            { name: "Loflin", firstname: "Wes", tag: "welo" },
            { name: "Hackett", firstname: "John", tag: "joha" }
        ]
    }
);
```

Or remove the as syntax.

Comment: So what if I **don't** use `controller as...` but just `ng-controller="mycontroller"` .... what do I have to use to setup the array properly?

Comment: this works, just change the `ng-repeat="m in vm.team"` to `ng-repeat="m in team"`. ControllerAs syntax is recommanded specially if you use a lot of `ng-controller`. Personnally i don't so i don't use it.

Comment: This is **madness** - so the way I'm going to use the controller later on in the code dictates how I must do the setup for any data members contained in the `$scope` ?!?!?!?!?? ***<shaking head in disbelief>***

Comment: It is recommended to use directives instead, it is easier when your code start to grow.

Comment: Yep that's why i use only one of the possibility and stick with it. controllerAs was added because some developers may got lost when using multiple controllers. Furthermore, when you have multiple scope inheriting with each other, you'll have some problem with the limit of inheritancy in javascript. So you'll have to use DOT notation and initialize prperly your data in the right controller (at least init them to ull if loading asynchronously). Check this for dot notation http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @OresteViron Directive are for reusability of a components which handle a functionnaility, a view. For a true application, in the OP post, it's better to have ngRoute or uiRouter that will handle navigation and display proper view using controller defined.

Comment: That's true. But maybe the directives are easier to handle for a start.

Comment: @OresteViron nope, directives are definitively the hardest thing in angular IMO. At least the hardest thing to understand at start with the scope isolation, controller, link,....

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications - much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

The "team" is in the $scope, so you can call "team" directly in your view :

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller as vm">
        <label>My company:</label>
        <hr>
        <div id="divTeam" ng-repeat="m in team">
            <p>
                {{m.firstname}} {{m.name}} ({{m.tag}})
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is the bind `this` to `vm` as follows (like [John Papa Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)):

JS Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.teams = [
        { name: "Brown", firstname: "Leo", tag: "lebr" },
        { name: "Smith", firstname: "Adrian", tag: "adsm" },
        { name: "Loflin", firstname: "Wes", tag: "welo" },
        { name: "Hackett", firstname: "John", tag: "joha" }
    ];
});
```

Here we don't need the `$scope` dependency since we won't use it.

And in the HTML, you use the following syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <div ng-repeat="team in mc.teams">
        <p>
            {{team.firstname}} {{team.name}} ({{team.tag}})
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second approach is to use `$scope` as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.teams = [
        { name: "Brown", firstname: "Leo", tag: "lebr" },
        { name: "Smith", firstname: "Adrian", tag: "adsm" },
        { name: "Loflin", firstname: "Wes", tag: "welo" },
        { name: "Hackett", firstname: "John", tag: "joha" }
    ];
});
```

Here we use `$scope`.

And in the HTML is like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="team in teams">
    <p>
        {{team.firstname}} {{team.name}} ({{team.tag}})
    </p>
</div>
```

Don't forget to bind the specific HTML page with the appropriate controller.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/myPage', {
            templateUrl: 'views/myPage.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'
        });
}]);
```

You can use `$routeProvider` or `$stateProvider`, whatever you decide.

Comment: Thanks especially for the link to John Papa's Style Guide - seems I still have *a lot* to learn in terms of Javascript + Angular!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `vm` from `vm.team`

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ulVb5lO3ZJOZejcnMSe)